# MySQL or Microsoft Sync Framework Synchronization / Replication

Tags: c#, mysql, synchronization, replication

I am creating an application that has one server and multiple clients.  It is a c# app that uses ADO.NET Entity Framework 4 over a MySQL database.

The clients need to get data from several database tables on the server. There are also 2 separate tables that need to be sent from the clients to the server.  At some point, the client should be able to delete some of the old data in these 2 tables and have it stay on the server.  The clients need to be able to work if they get disconnected from the server for some time and tables need to be updated at some point after reconnection.

I was thinking about going with MySQL replication but I don't think the client would be able to delete old data without effecting the server tables.  I have looked at Microsoft sync framework as well, but I am not sure if that is ideal or would even work for my needs.

I don't know a lot about this subject so some direction would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Matt W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with MySql replication for the data the server sends to the clients since it is the same for every database.  For the tables that the client sends to the server, I serialize the table entity objects and send them to the server which deserializes them and adds them to its database.